# SAP UI5 version 1.108.20 propertyChange alternative

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori

The class `sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataModel` in version `1.108.20` does not support the `propertyChange` event, according to the [documentation](https://sdk.openui5.org/1.108.20/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataModel%23events/propertyChange) .

[image]

However, the `propertyChange` event is supported up to version 1.110.0. Is there any other event that can be used to observe `Two-Way Data Binding` changes?

I have created a video to show you what I am trying to achieve.
[image]

The value of the `Field Description` column depends on the `Fieldname` column. Therefore, whenever a new value is selected in the `Fieldname` column, it should display the corresponding `Field Description`. Currently, the change is only applied after the page has been refreshed.

According to the `propertyChange` event documentation for the newest version of UI5, it states:

> The propertyChange event is fired whenever one of this model's
> property bindings successfully changes its value due to two-way data
> binding. This does not apply to
> sap.ui.model.odata.v4.Context#setProperty which represents controller
> code changes, not user input.

Unfortunately, the UI5 version `1.108.20` does not support the `propertyChange` event. Is there an alternative event that offers similar functionality?

**The app is built with Fiori elements, therefore the controller needs to be extended to listen on the event.**

Answer (score 1):

The annotation `@ObjectModel.text.element: ['DocumentTypeText']`  in the ABAP CDS has solved the issue.

```
          @ObjectModel.text.element: ['DocumentTypeText'] 
          @Consumption.valueHelpDefinition: [{  entity: {   name: 'C_DocumentTypeVH' ,
                                                            element: 'DocumentType'  }     }]
  key     DocumentType,
          @ObjectModel.virtualElementCalculatedBy: 'ABAP:CL_SENSITIVEFIELDITEM_VEC'
  virtual DocumentTypeText     : /opt/doctypetext,
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Side Effects](https://learning.sap.com/learning-journey/developing-an-sap-fiori-elements-app-based-on-a-cap-odata-v4-service/configuring-side-effects_a7e5f948-c568-4cb9-acb4-37073eb958fa)?